# Spring XML handler Mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

it is possible to specify a request method type in SimpleUrlHandlerMapping or other XML handlerMapper  via XML configuration?? And invocation of controller method too??

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
   <property name="order" value="1" />
   <property name="mappings">
     <props>
       <prop key="/welcome.htm" >clinicController</prop> 
       // something like <prop key="/welcome.htm" method="GET" controllerMethod="someMethod1 ..."
       <prop key="/vets.htm">clinicController</prop>  
       // something like <prop key="/vets.htm" method=PUT method="GET" controllerMethod="someMethod2 ..."
       <prop key="/meds.htm">clinicController</prop>  
       // something like <prop key="/meds.htm" method=POST method="GET" controllerMethod="someMethod3 ..."
     </props>
   </property>
</bean>
```

i trying to find answer but i cant find nothing. I preffer to use XML configuration instead annotation. But in annotation is possible using

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/welcome.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. SimpleUrlHandlerMapping is in fact a legacy spring HandlerMapping implementation that was mostly useful with the old style pre-2.5 mvc model. In that model you had to extend specific controller classes, so the behaviour was preconfigured (i.e. a standard workflow per controller kind was enforced on each request). In other words, a GET or POST method was handled by predefined abstract or concrete methods you might override.
Consequently, this pattern made the method type mapping redundant.

Prior to Spring 3.1 you could even mix the two patterns to some degree. It was possible to use  SimpleUrlHandlerMapping to map the controller beans to some url prefix, and further refine by method type (or by the rest of the url part or parameters etc), towards controller methods by using annotations.  This was possible because the bean and method mappings were made at different points.  Spring reference is explicit on this :

> Prior to Spring 3.1, type and method-level request mappings were
>   examined in two separate stages — a controller was selected first by
>   the DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping and the actual method to invoke
>   was narrowed down second by the AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter. With
>   the new support classes in Spring 3.1, the
>   RequestMappingHandlerMapping is the only place where a decision is
>   made about which method should process the request. Think of
>   controller methods as a collection of unique endpoints with mappings
>   for each method derived from type and method-level @RequestMapping
>   information.

In general, today annotation-driven mvc is the preferred way and far more flexible than the old style one. Since IDEs -like STS- now provide ways to inspect all your handler mappings in one view, I can't see any real disadvantage. Of course this is just my opinion, so you can safely ignore it but at least weight the advantages of each approach.